# Calling c/c++ code from C# .net

Tags: c++, c#-3.0

I have got a DLL in native code, and i need to call a specific function from that DLL from c# code.

Signature of the function is this:

`long Validate(char *p)`.

please help me on this.

We are using ZP4 for Address verification. From Semaphore tutorial they have mentioned that for checking the software is expired or not , we can call a function long `ValidateZP4(char *p)` by importing a specific dll. If the software is expired it will give us a 0 or -1. But when try to use this function it is giving me big 5 digit number , may be because of my code. i will past my code below

```
[DllImport("ZP4VALID.DLL")] 
public static extern long ValidateZP4(string p);
```

and I am calling it like

```
long valid = ZP4.ValidateZP4("0");
```

Comment: That would be `long Validate(string p)` in C# but you really need to provide more details.

Comment: Please follow [general question guidelines](http://tinyurl.com/so-hints), state any special restrictions, show what you've tried so far, and ask about what specifically is confusing you.

Comment: @user502855: Changed your question due to the comment you gave below. Please feel free to change it again if I missed your intention what you really wanted to ask.